# yeoman angular firebase AUTHENTICATION_DISABLED

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I set up a project using yeoman generator for angularfire according to the [instructions here](https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire).

However when I try to register or login, i get the following error:

```
{"code":"AUTHENTICATION_DISABLED"}
```

I have already enabled firebase authentication in firebase console, for email/password auth.

The [firebase site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) says to include the following code snippet, but I don't know where I should put this after yeoman has generated the app.

```
// Initialize Firebase
// TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
var config = {
  apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: That generator is likely targeted at the Firebase 2.x Authentication SDK, which unfortunately won't work with a project created on firebase.google.com. You'll have to find an updated generator or start from the [AngularFire documentation](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/), which has been updated for the new 3.x SDK.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  do you know of any email password firebase auth example on github?